# Splitting a WHERE sql clause into array

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, split

I am trying to split a String which is the WHERE clause of a SQL statement into an array with 5 outputs where the following data is hold under each index:

```
0 - The initial clauses (WHERE/AND/OR) plus any open brackets. e.g "AND((("
1 - Either the table the first clause comes from or "VALUE" if its a value. e.g. "transactions". 
2 - The field name or value. e.g. "id"
3 - The joining value. e.g. >
4 - Either the table the second clause comes from or "VALUE" if its a value. e.g. "transactions". 
5 - The field name or value. e.g. "id"
6 - Any closing brackets. e.g. ")))"
```

For example looping through the following String would output the following arrays:

```
WHERE transactions.status_code= 'AFA 2'
AND (transactions.supp_ref = supplier.supp_ref
AND supplier.supp_addr_ref = address.addr_ref)
OR transactions.user_code = user.user_code

output[0] = "WHERE"
output[1] = "transactions"
output[2] = "status_code"
output[3] = "="
output[4] = "VALUE'
output[5] = "AFA 2"
output[6] = ""

output[0] = "AND("
output[1] = "transactions"
output[2] = "supp_ref"
output[3] = "="
output[4] = "supplier"
output[5] = "supp_ref"
output[6] = ""

output[0] = "AND"
output[1] = "supplier"
output[2] = "supp_addr_ref"
output[3] = "="
output[4] = "address"
output[5] = "addr_ref"
output[6] = ")"

output[0] = "OR"
output[1] = "transactions"
output[2] = "user_code"
output[3] = "="
output[4] = "user"
output[5] = "user_code"
output[6] = ""
```

For the rest of the SQL statement I have successfully split it up in similar ways using the String.Split method, however due to the variances of the where clause I am having difficulties doing this on this part. From looking around I think I would be better using a Regex expression, but cant work out whats needed. Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: While I can't answer on your question itself, _why_ do you need to parse SQL? That isn't a trivial task. What underlying problem are you trying to solve, what will you do with the tokenized SQL?

Comment: What it there is BETWEEN, IN or some sub query?

Comment: I don't need to support sub queries. I agree it might seem like a crazy task, however the system I am using stores SQL queries split into different columns in a database - so that "novice" users can create SQL queries using a GUI front end. Unfortunately I have no way of changing this system - hence the requirement to split up the query.

Comment: It would be cheaper to train your novices in SQL fundementals than go through this charade.  If you have a front end then why do you need to parse SQL?  You're onto a loser here.  The only proper way to actually approach this problem from the technical aspect is to write or acquire a SQL parser but I think your premise is flawed.

Comment: I agree with @LoztInSpace. It would really be cheaper in both time and logic and memory all aspects to train your novice users to use SQL. Still if that is not possible, go through below link. Maybe it provides such UI which your users require. http://executequery.org/index.jsp

Comment: any regex doing the job will require an engine supporting recursive matches and will still be overly complex as you effectively need to emulate an expression parser and cater for the possibility of operators occurring inside string literals with escape symbols (e.g. perversion like `WHERE condition_a AND 'condition_b\' AND \'condition\\\'' AND ...` ). if you manage to build a suitable pattern it will be a nightmare to maintain. also keep in mind that as soon as have the beast going, demands to support subqueries will probably pop up. in a nutshell: don't do it.

Comment: some approach could be trying to split the where clause at top level  operators with a simple heuristic ( eg. matching against `AND`, `OR` etc. only) and after doing so to attempt using increasingly shortened copies in queries against the db (eg: `where a AND b OR c AND d` -> `select count(*) from x where a AND b OR c`, `select count(*) from x where a AND b`, `select count(*) from x where a`). syntactically wrong segmentations will produce errors indicating that the occurrence dropped last was either not an op or not on top level. caveat: just an untested idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first off I think regex might not be the best fit for what you are trying to do. That being said Here is a regex that will parse what you have posted and turn it into what you are looking for:

```
(?<Group>(?<Concat>where|\s*?\)?\s*?and\s*?\(?|\s*?\)?\s*?or\s*?\(?)(?<TableName>[\w\s]+(?=\.))\.?(?<ColName>.+?(?=\=|like|between|\<\>|\>\=|\<\=|in|\>|\<))\s*?(?<Compare>\=|like|between|\<\>|\>\=|\<\=|in|\>|\<)(?<Value>.*?(?=\s*?and\s*?\(*|or\*?\(*)|.*))
```

I'm sure this doesn't cover everything and depending on the regex parser this might behave differently. I use  [The Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/) for my regex work.

I would suggest writing a parser that does this. Take a look at what I have below, it might help if you decide to go this route. I wasn't entirely sure what you were doing with that "VALUE" string you have there but if you are looking to identify what is a value and what is a table.colName you could easily add that to this. It's going to be harder to identify things like in ('a', 'b') but I think it is dooable.

```
    //A list of chars that we are going to replace with \s"char"\s this list may not be complete.
    // . is not in here. We will take care of that later.
    static string[] specChars = new string[] { "<", ">", "<=", ">=", "=", "like", "in", "between", "or", "and", "(", ")", "where" };
    static string[] delims = new string[] {"and", "or", "where" };
    static string testData = @"WHERE transactions.status_code= 'AFA 2'
    AND (transactions.supp_ref = supplier.supp_ref
    AND supplier.supp_addr_ref = address.addr_ref)
    OR transactions.user_code = user.user_code";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Print(Parse(testData));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static List<List<string>> Parse(string input)
    {
        List<List<string>> ret = new List<List<string>>();
        //lets remove all the spaces first becaue we are going to put them back
        //the way we want to see them.
        input = input.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").ToLower();
        foreach (string item in specChars)
        {
            //this will help clean the string so you can use it
            input = input.Replace(item, string.Format(" {0} ", item));   
        }
        string[] splits = input.Split(' ');

        List<string> currList = null;
        foreach (string item in splits.Where(x => x.Length > 0))
        {
            if (delims.Contains(item))
            {
                if (currList != null)
                {
                    ret.Add(currList);
                    currList = new List<string>();
                    currList.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    currList = new List<string>();
                    currList.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (item.Contains("."))
                {
                    string[] tmp = item.Split('.');
                    currList.Add(tmp[0]);
                    currList.Add(tmp[1]);
                }
                else
                    currList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        if (currList != null)
            ret.Add(currList);
        return ret;
    }

    static void Print(List<List<String>> input)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (List<String> item in input)
        {
            sb.Append("New Chunk:\n");
            foreach (string str in item)
            {
                sb.Append(string.Format("\t{0}\n", str));
            }
            sb.Append("\n");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to parse SQL, you might want to look into the ScriptDom namespace.  It might be more than what you're looking to do, but it has some SQL parsers that will give you great detail about a given SQL query.

Here are a couple of resources.

[MSDN ScriptDOM reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.aspx)
[An easier introduction](https://crismorris.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/scriptdom-part-1-introduction/)